How can I check current process capabilities in Linux
I'm writing a server and would like to check if the process has the capability to open a port below 1024, and use a port above 1024 otherwise.
How could this be done under Linux in C/C++?
The obvious solution is to just try, but that is less elegant as I use third party software (GstRtspServer) that will subsequently use the port I've chosen accordingly. So that solution would be to open port 554 and if successful close it and tell GstRtspServer to use port 554 and otherwise 8554.

Note: 1024 is not hard limit. There is sysctl "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start" for changing the limit.

Maybe use sockets and try binding to that port? If it throws an error, then you know that the port is not available?

@kiner_shah That solution was already mentioned in the question as being less elegant.

@skyking, it's better not to use third party software to check that, Linux sockets can do it as well.

@kiner_shah Is the quesion that hard to understand? I tried to reword it to hopefully make it more clear. I'm not using third part SW to check that. I want to check that before I tell the third part SW to run the RTSP server. I use third party SW to implement an RTSP server.

@skyking, aah, now it makes sense.

Read whether you have CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE using cap_get_proc.  See https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

Even if you get a positive answer on the question "is port open?", there is no guarantee that in the next microsecond it is still open

Just an idea, maybe the source code of the netstat tool may help you

@DmytroOvdiienko Unfortunately the title became a bit misleading. I'm interrested in determine the process capabilities. If then the opening of the port fails it at leas not because lacking capabilities. I'm not sure netstat listing capabilities of processes.

@skyking IMO you should be a Root to open the port below 1024. See https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux

Why do you think that trying the capability is inelegant? Use GstRtspServer to attempt to open 554, and if that fails then open 8554.  If GstRtspServer does not handle that use case well, perhaps file a bug with them.  Or find out how that library intends callers to handle it. If they don't have a suitable approach, fix it or use a different library.  It is a common use case.

@DmytroOvdiienko That was true before capabilities were added to the kernel, now non-root programs can be given this ability.

@WilliamPursell I noted that it looks like GstRtspServer is reporting that back as an error when attaching it to the main loop and should be possible to act accordingly.

@DmytroOvdiienko I disagree, being root implies full capabilities, at least that's what it used to mean. Giving a process all capabilities just in order to give it one is an unessicaty risk.

the comment of mr. Stark is right.
look at "man capabilities"
CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
Bind a socket to Internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).
see include/linux/capability.h and man of libcap-dev/capgetp.3

This is straightforward in C/C++ (check.c):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cap_t current = cap_get_proc();
    if (current == NULL) {
        perror("failed to get process capabilities");
        exit(1);
    }
    cap_flag_value_t on;
    if (cap_get_flag(current, CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE, CAP_PERMITTED, &on) != 0) {
        perror("failed to check cap_net_bind_service value");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("the current process %s permitted to use cap_net_bind_service\n",
       on == CAP_SET ? "is" : "is not");
}

Compile and run it:
$ cc check.c -lcap
$ ./a.out
the current process is not permitted to use cap_net_bind_service
$ sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=p ./a.out
$ ./a.out 
the current process is permitted to use cap_net_bind_service

To actually use this capability, you can change that setcap command to set cap_net_bind_service=ep, or use libcap's cap_fill() and cap_set_proc() to copy the Permitted flag values into the Effective flag.

An easy way is to make some assumptions that are probably going to be true most of the time: see if you are running as root using geteuid():
#include <unistd.h>
...
uid_t euid = geteuid();
if (euid == 0) {
   you_can_open_ports_below_1024
}

The problem with this solution is that it will just probably work on most systems that you're likely to encounter ... unless it doesn't. Modern Unix systems have ways to allow non-root to have various permissions that ancient Unixes reserved for root only.
So really, the best (albeit inelegant) way is in fact to try to open the socket, and close it if successful. If not successful, you should check errno to see if it's permission, in-use, or whatever. If it's in-use, then you haven't really answered the question if you have permission, but the question is moot at that point.
As for trying to determine the process' capabilities, trying to write code to actually check the permissions explicitly will be a headache, be non-portable (even across different Linuxes, never mind Solaris, etc), and ultimately break as security procedures continue to evolve.
And by the way, it is also true that you might open it successfully, then close it, and then try to open it again and fail ... not because you don't have permission, but because some other program slipped in. That does not invalidate this method. The open/close cycle is checking for permission. If the subsequent open fails because it's in-use by somebody else, then that could have happened no matter how you check for permission.

Fun trick: sudo /sbin/capsh --mode=PURE1E_INIT -- will put you into a shell as root but without any privileges. Long write-up of what is going on: https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/inheriting-privilege
